# What is the meaning of s,t,p,q in Vector components?

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, webgl2

In the [WebGL reference card](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf), there is the documentation about Vector components.

While it seems to me that i can use also {x, y, z, w}, I am not able to understand if it is mandatory to use {s, t, p, q} when reading from Textures.

> Use when accessing vectors that represent texture  coordinates

What is the meaning of the {s, t, p, q} letters? It is just only a matter of convention for readable code or is there something more that i am missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [WebGL Specification Vesion 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.0/#4.3):

> 4.3 Supported GLSL Constructs
>
> A WebGL implementation must only accept shaders which conform to The OpenGL ES Shading Language, Version 1.00 ...

See the [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) :

> 5.5 Vector Components
>
> The names of the components of a vector or scalar are denoted by a single letter. As a notational convenience, several letters are associated with each component based on common usage of position, color or texture coordinate vectors. The individual components can be selected by following the variable
> name with period ( . ) and then the component name.
>
> The component names supported are:
>
> - `{x, y, z, w}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent points or normals
> - `{r, g, b, a}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent colors
> - `{s, t, p, q}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent texture coordinates
>
> The component names `x`, `r`, and `s` are, for example, synonyms for the same (first) component in a vector.
> Note that the third component of the texture coordinate set, `r` in OpenGL ES, has been renamed `p` so as to avoid the confusion with `r` (for red) in a color.

You can also use `v[0]`, `v[1]`, `v[2]`, `v[3]` to access the components of a the vector.

This means for a `vec4 v;`, `v.stpq` is exactly the same as `v.xyzw` or `v.rgba`.

The `s`, `t` naming comes from the [Plane (geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29), where a plan can be described parametrically as the set of all points of the form *R = R<sub>0</sub> + s*V + t*W*. (*R* and *R<sub>0</sub>* are points, *V* and *W* are vectors, *s* and *t* are real numbers.

Comment: For completeness you can also use `v[0]`, `v[1]`, `v[2]`, `v[3]` to access individual members of a vec4.